# Best practice for applying complex business logic during transformation in ETL from Aurora db to Redshift data warehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, best-practices, etl, redshift, aws-aurora

I'll be pushing data from an Amazon Aurora db to a Redshift data warehouse. The painful part is that the transformation portion of the ETL workflow relies *heavily* on business logic, that lives within an application's codebase, in order to be derived into a useful format for the data warehouse. We don't want to remove the business logic from the application layer.

My thinking is a couple of different options.

Option 1:

Using AWS Glue as the ETL framework

1. Extract data
2. Apply business logic on that data by calling an API (via AWS Glue Network Connection) that applies the business logic during transformation
3. Load into Redshift

Option 2:

1. Hourly background job in application to extract records that need to be pushed to Redshift
2. Apply business logic on that data in the background job, transform, and stage it in a table on Aurora
3. Use AWS Glue to load from Aurora to Redshift

All these tools are new to me, so it's difficult to know which to use. Glue, DMS, Data Pipeline? Any advice?

Comment: "*Any advice?*" - Don't store business logic in the application layer. Despite what the developers think, storing it in the data layer makes it more centric and refactored for other consumers so one doesn't have these problems.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I work on a team of developers so that's a new concept to me. DBA's usually handle that via stored procedures?

Comment: It just depends on the business, business logic, and use cases. It doesn't matter what object you use to store it, so long as that object is able to accurately provide the data with the business logic applied, and in a performant enough manner. Stored procedures are a common implementation since it maximizes your flexibility for performance tuning, but it makes consumability a little tougher. I'm personally currently managing things mostly with views, or in the native tables (sometimes with computed columns), with some cases of stored procedures or table values functions.